# How do I display a large image when rolling over a thumbnail that allows text to be written over the large image

Tags: slideshow

I have images in a table and want to click on each and have them enlarged on the screen.  I can find alot of these snippets online but none I have found allow for writing text over the enlarged images.  These pix are artwork and need a copywrite statement on top of them when enlarged.  Anyone know either how to do this or where to find it online....thx....David

Comment: you have edit all your images before showing them to public.

Comment: evidently i am not being clear.  these are copywrited images and cannot be modified.  i have a script that displays full screen images based on rollover of a thumbnail.  what i want is to write text over the image and i realize that is not possible so what i need is some way to have it open another document using the thumbnail image as the page background and then write the text on top of that.  i hope this clarifys my problem.

Comment: <div style="background:image.jpg; width:100px; height:100px;">your copy right text</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can find to add text over an image is to create the image as the background.  Setting up a division and table allowed me to only have the background apply to a certain area of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

```
<div id="lare_img">
<div class="copyright">Your copy right text here </div><div class="img_file"><img src="img_01.jpg"></div></div>
```

and style CSS :

```
<style>

#lare_img{
  width:100% // change to your image large width ;
  height:100% // change to your image large height;
  position:absolute;
}

.copyright{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:20px;
 left:20px;
 z-index:999;
}

.img_file{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 float:left;
}

</style>
```